# C# how to let two columns be with the same column header using datagridview windows form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I used the datatable class to collect data and then bound it to the datagridview **windows form**.
I am wondering if it is possible to make such change, as the attached image shows?

Thanks
[need to put two columns at one column header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3SKD.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [colspan gridview rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936417/colspan-gridview-rows)

Comment: This cannot work since it is suited for gridview in web application.

Comment: check out here: [paint rectangle on column header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676251/paint-rectangle-on-column-header)

Comment: This is not really supported. You can try to workaround with ownerdrawing the headers but it probably won't be nice..

Answer (score 0):

In your gridview rowdatabound:

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
          e.Row.Cells[1].ColumnSpan = 2;
          e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;
          e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Optimized";
    }
```

Comment: This is windows form application rather than web control, so I don't think it can work.